# Google Maps Elevation API Not Returning Results (JSON/PHP)

Tags: php, json, api, maps, elevation

I am trying to use the Google Maps Elevation API but its not returning any results. The code I am using is below:

```
<?php
$results = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=-37.8,144.815&key=[myAPIkey]&sensor=false");
//$results = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris,France&sensor=false&key=[myAPIkey]");
$json = json_decode($results, true);
echo ${results};
//print_r($json); ?>
```

The commented parts are using the Geocoding API which works for me but as soon as I change the $results variable to the Elevation API it does not return any results at all. When I put the URL in my browser I get results.I have enabled the API in the console and have a working API key.

Has anyone got any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Use `return $json;` instead of `echo ${results};`

Comment: Still returns 0 results. file_get_contents() returns a string so "echo ${results};" should work fine. I even changed it to be "echo $results;" just to be sure

Comment: Ok, with google api, you have to specify the domains names where you can use the key. Have you done that ?

Comment: I setup geocoding awhile ago so that might be the case, where exactly do you set it up ?

Comment: Don't remember. Search on google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure on your API console that **Elevation API is enabled** and your **browser application key** have `Any referrer allowed` or if you use **server application key** `Any IP allowed`

Otherwise try using cURL

```
$curlUrlRequest = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=-37.8,144.815&key=[myApiKey]&sensor=false';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrlRequest);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Setting the two options CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER solved my problem, thanks